# The problem when adding to a telegram chat using Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I am new to python. I am trying to use the telethon shell to add and remove users from a chat.
I use the example code taken from here https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/add_chat_user.html

My code:

(ID and hash I replaced in the text with arbitrary numbers)

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.errors import ChatIdInvalidError
from telethon.errors import PeerIdInvalidError
from telethon.errors import UserNotParticipantError
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import DeleteChatUserRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import AddChatUserRequest


api_id = 1234567
api_hash = 'blablablabla123456'
phone = '+123456789'
name = 'testname'

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.messages.AddChatUserRequest(
        chat_id=12345678912,
        user_id='username',
        fwd_limit=42
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

But unfortunately for me it doesn't work and gives an error.

(ID and hash I replaced in the text with arbitrary numbers.)

```
    Request caused struct.error: argument out of range: AddChatUserRequest(chat_id=123456789, user_id=InputUser(user_id=123456789, access_hash=-123456789789), fwd_limit=42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\AddUser\new\from telethon.tl.functions.messages impo.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = client(functions.messages.AddChatUserRequest(
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py", line 39, in syncified
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__      
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 58, in _call
    future = sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 176, in send
    state = RequestState(request)
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\requeststate.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.data = bytes(request)
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\tlobject.py", line 194, in __bytes__
    return self._bytes()
  File "c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telethon\tl\functions\messages.py", line 139, in _bytes
    struct.pack('<i', self.chat_id),
struct.error: argument out of range
```

Telethon ver. 1.22.0

I would be grateful for any help

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "argument out of range" error I which indicated in the question,  occurred because I was trying to specify a 40 byte Chat_id. Whereas for regular chats, the maximum id is 32 bytes.

This happened as you need to specify the so-called "real" id.
As an example, the id that Telegram bots receive looks something like this -1001234567891
the real id would be 1234567891.

You can use the following code to get the real id:

```
from telethon import utils
real_id, peer_type = utils.resolve_id(-1001234567891)

print(real_id)  # 1234567891
print(peer_type)  # <class 'telethon.tl.types.PeerChannel'>

peer = peer_type(real_id)
print(peer)  # PeerChannel(channel_id=1234567891)
```

However, if you specify a real id, a ChatIdInvalidError may appear. The problem is that the AddChatUserRequest method can only be used with regular "chats"
In my case, it was "supergroup" -
is a Channel with the channel.megagroup attribute set to True

For them need use InviteToChannelRequest method, the code that worked was like this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
    
api_id = 123456
api_hash = '******'
name = 'name'
    
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.InviteToChannelRequest(
            channel='channelname',
            users = ['username']
        ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

Then I created a regular "chat" group

For her, the working code was like this:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
    
api_id = 123456
api_hash = '*******'
name = 'name'
      
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
   result = client(functions.messages.AddChatUserRequest(
        chat_id=chatid,
        user_id='username',
        fwd_limit=42
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

Comment: but i got same error while im using the id of my group on your last example, are you sure if your solution solved the issue?

Comment: I found out to solve this issue you have to follow the error message when it says use `functions.channels.InviteToChannelRequest`  for `megagroup`/`channels` . megagroup are large groups. I couldn't find this information actually on the guide they only mentioned channels, but the error msg was helpful more. here you go for further information: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html?highlight=InviteToChannelRequest#adding-someone-else-to-such-chat-or-channel

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
result = await client(functions.messages.AddChatUserRequest(
        chat_id=12345678912,
        user_id='username',
        fwd_limit=42
    ))
```

Instead of:

```
result =  client(functions.messages.AddChatUserRequest(
        chat_id=12345678912,
        user_id='username',
        fwd_limit=42
    ))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: If you didn't know how to use async, then you can also remove .sync from telethon.sync

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried this.
But again I got an error.

  `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods .__ call__' was never awaited`

After spending some time I was able to write code with an async function. And having defeated one more error, I returned to where I started.

`struct.error: argument out of range`

Any more ideas? :-)

My code 
Ver 1 [link](https://pastebin.com/Puunrww0)
Ver 2 [link](https://pastebin.com/rzAa4Z8z)

both lead to the same result

Comment: I changed your code and it seems to work. (read the comments in the code)
https://pastebin.com/4d9CwbZB

Comment: Thank you for your help.
It turned out that the problem was not entirely in the code, but in the API features. What I wanted to do would only work with regular Chat (Group).
In my case, there was a megagroup. There are other methods for her.
I will write a detailed answer later.